# How to decide whether to assume 2 Gene Losses or 1 to find minimum cost trees for Gene Duplication/Expression events?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, gene-expression

[This](https://doi.org/10.2307/2412519) paper introduces an approach to estimate a convergence from discord between phylogenetic species trees and gene trees, using Gene Duplication and Expression events.

A **Gene Duplication (GD)** event refers to when a bifurcation of the phylogenetic gene tree occurs creating two duplicate gene loci. The first image marks them in solid white diamonds.

A **Gene Expression (GE)** event refers to the **loss** or **Regulatory Mutation (RM)** of genes. The types are:

- Gene Loss (marked by the cross in the first image) refers to when a locus is lost/deleted along the lineage of an extant species.
- Gene Inactivation (marked by the unfilled downward caret in the first image) refers to a *Regulatory Mutation* where a gene is rendered inactive.
- Gene Reactivation (marked by the unfilled upward caret in the first image) refers to a *Regulatory Mutation* where a previously inactivated gene is reactivated and sampled in extant species.

Now, in the event of a discord between a gene tree and a species tree, we can attempt to establish concordance through assumptions about hypothetical duplication and expression events. The gene tree with a minimum count of (GD + GE) is the most likely assumption for concordance.

In the first image, the **right locus** resulting from the **second bifurcation** of the gene tree is sampled in extant species C and D and undergoes a **loss** event for species E. I would assume that it would also undergo a **loss** event for species A and B but the paper merges those two loss events into one.

On the other hand, based on the second image from [this](https://doi.org/10.1093/sysbio/46.3.523) paper, I've simulated the Gene Duplication/Expression events on the gene tree and found that if such loss events are merged into one, the Duplication/Expression (D/E in the table) count I calculate is lower than what is mentioned in the table.

I'm confused as to whether there is an appropriate approach to this. The author of the [first](https://doi.org/10.2307/2412519) paper mentions that such assumptions regarding Gene Duplication and Expression events are not at all representative of real Gene Duplication and Expression events (established through observed evidence) and serve as a mechanism to approach likely solutions to discordance between species trees and gene trees.

My question is, how do I arrive at the minimum cost tree?

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]